# Rails Devise not detecting user as logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am currently having an issue with Devise where before_filter :authenticate_user! always asks the user to sign in even if he has already signed in

I have an index page where users can login. Once logged in the user can click a button that takes him to another view. On that view he can issue commands to a Controller that has a before_filter :authenticate_user! setup. It looks like the filter is always redirecting the user to the sign in page

Could I be using devise in a wrong way ? I haven't customized anything yet, just using it out of the box. Does the user have to select the remember me option even if he is navigating between controllers in the same application ? Could there be a problem with how the session is persisted ?

Rails : '3.0.10'

Devise : '1.4.3'

Edit: This problem happens even with remember me ticked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Devise uses session cookies. Does your browser allow cookies?

Comment: Yep. Inspected the cookie storage using chrome dev tools and found : _devise_example_session and _<myAppName>_session